# Tomcat doesn't see my CONTEXT.XML when trying to connect from Servlet also i use IDEA Intellij

Tags: java, database, tomcat, servlets

I am not sure why tomcat can't see **WEB-INF/context.xml**, Als I don't have **folder META-INF** in IntelliJ.

I get an exception: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'.

I really like IntelliJ but this problem it's making me angry, I tried this code in eclipse it works but at IntelliJ doesn't. Does anyone know why?

*I am really new to all of this.*

This is the code from servlet file "TestServlet":

```
package com.luv2code.web.jdbc;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

@WebServlet(name = "TestServlet", urlPatterns = {"/TestServlet"})
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Resource(name = "jdbc/web_student_tracker")
    private DataSource dataSource;


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // Step 1: set up printWriter
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/plain");

        // Step 2: get a connection to database
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;

        try {
            connection = dataSource.getConnection();

            // Step 3: create sql statement
            String sql = "select * from student";
            statement = connection.createStatement();

            // Step 4: Execute SQL query
            resultSet = statement.getResultSet();

            // Step 5: process the results
            while (resultSet.next()){
                String email = resultSet.getString("email");
                out.println(email);
                System.out.println(email);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

This is the code from context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>

    <Resource name="jdbc/web_student_tracker"
              auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              maxActive="20" maxIdle="5" maxWait="10000"
              username="webstudent" password="webstudent"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_student_tracker"/>
</Context>
```

Here is the screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

File `context.xml` is belong to Apache Tomcat. When Apache Tomcat start, it reads file `context.xml`, Tomcat look for class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`, but it cannot find.

Put file `mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar` to `%CATALINA_HOME%\lib`, not in `lib` directory of web-app.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I tried that it didn't work, same error.

Comment: Don't worry. Read all this page, and type code like this https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Code_Example

Comment: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#MySQL_DBCP_Example

Comment: Can you tell me is context.xml in the right folder?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, the reason that didn't work tomcat was that I had the old version of jdbc jar but I was using tomcat v9 so that's why i didn't sleep for 2 days.